# Dissmis a modal viewcontroller on a Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

I'm developing an iPhone application with latest SDK.

I don't know how to dismiss a ViewController. I've added a back button and this is what I do:

```
- (IBAction)backButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I have also tried:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But either works. I've added a breakpoint and it stops on it.

And I use a `Modal segue` to navigate to this ViewController.

**How can I dismiss this View Controller programmatically?**

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: The modal view controller is not in a navigation controller so its navigationController property is nil and so your line of code does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)backButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                      completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: deprecated - see Levi's answer

Answer (score 1):

Try `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

Is the VC being modally displayed an instance of your own view controller subclass, or did you wrap that inside a UINavigationController? If the former, try

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

`[self.presentingViewController dismiss...]` will also work, but only for iOS 5+

Comment: dismissModalViewController is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

create a custom segue,then button action choose the custom segue
http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/02/19/dismissing-a-modal-view-using-a-storyboard-segue